# How can i make a custom Holo EditText that looks like this one

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-xml

I just want to change the background of the Holo EditText to green.

Something like this: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2n20k8l&s=8#.U6hMQ_ldWSo

It may be a stupid question but i searched and with no results! Thanks!

Comment: which one could you show some images or link?

Comment: try `android:background="#0f0"` in the XML of the layout

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks enough information to identify the problem.

Comment: I tired to change the bg color it didnt work

Comment: here is the link [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2n20k8l/8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code to achieve what you want.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="#006400" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your XML, add the property to your EditText:

```
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
```

OR

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="edit"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this colors min API is 14 .. my Apps min API is 8

Comment: simple change LinearLayout backgroud